# Rails 3 Rake Task: uninitialized constant RemedyImporter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

I have the following rake task:

```
# lib/tasks/remedy_import.rake

namespace :remedy do

  desc "Import remedy site IDs for representations"
  task :import_site_ids => :environment do
    puts "Importing site IDs..."
    RemedyImporter.import_site_ids!
  end

  desc "Import devices from remedy"
  task :import_devices => :environment do
    puts "Importing devices..."
    RemedyImporter.import_devices!
  end

end
```

When i run RemedyImporter.import_site_ids! or RemedyImporter.import_devices! in the Rails Console it works perfectly fine.

But in the command line i got the following error:

```
C:\Appl_ruby\WebFacts\WebFacts>bundle exec rake remedy:import_devices --trace
** Invoke remedy:import_devices (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute remedy:import_devices
Importing devices...
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant RemedyImporter
```

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're running the rake task in production (maybe via an environment variable)?  If so, the application won't be eager loaded (unless you've tweaked the files in config/environments).